# Read instructions from files in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a text file with commands to, say, create a table. How do I execute all the instructions in this file? I'm only acquainted with using the prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect with MySQL Command Prompt.

Run:

```
source /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 2):

Do keep in mind that you will also probably need to pass your credentials.

You can always use < operator:

```
$ mysql < your_file.sql
```

Comment: `mysql db_name < your_file.sql` is also useful sometimes